# How to create binary dummy variables out of a column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have df:

```
ID  Age
1   32   
2   58 
3   39   
4   67
5   72 
6   74 
7   23
```

I would like to create dummy age variables for four age brackets. Age1 = 18-34, Age2 = 35-50, Age3 = 51-64, Age4 = 65+. How is this done?

```
ID  Age   Age1   Age2   Age3   Age4
1   32    1      0      0      0
2   58    0      0      1      0
3   39    0      1      0      0
4   67    0      0      0      1
5   72    0      0      0      1
6   74    0      0      0      1
7   23    1      0      0      0
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `cut` with `model.matrix`

```
df[paste0("Age", 1:4)] <-  model.matrix(~ cut(df$Age,
         breaks = c(18, 35, 50, 65, Inf)) - 1)
```